# Encrypt a flash drive for GNU/Linux (and maybe Windows)

Tags: open-source, encryption, usb, debian

I want to put sensitive data on a flashdrive. [Flashdrives are notoriously easy to recover deleted data from](https://www.howtogeek.com/187104/warning-anyone-can-recover-deleted-files-from-your-usb-drives-and-external-ssds/), so I want to encrypt the drive first.

I'm looking for a free/libre application, preferably already packaged in Debian. Ideally the drive would also be readable by a Windows machine, but that would be a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/), the truecrypt fork, can be used both on windows and linux.

Comment: On Debian, that would probably mean the "zulucrypt" packages. Quoting from the description: *zulucrypt is a suite of applications for creating and managing volumes encrypted with luks, plain, truecrypt and veracrypt.*

Comment: I believe cryptsetup can also work. At least [cryptsetup man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cryptsetup.8.html) claims support for opening truecrypt volumes.

Comment: I've mentioned Zulucrypt because you recommended Veracrypt – and from what's in Debian's packages (as OP requested), Zulucrypt is the only one explicitly mentioning Veracrypt (I run multiple machines with Debian, so I checked).

Comment: [man crypsetup on my debian](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cryptsetup-bin/cryptsetup.8.en.html) does mention truecrypt and veracrypt, maybe you don't have the latest version

Comment: I don't have any version, I just checked the package description :) But maybe you could [edit] your answer and include the details from the comments, and then we do a cleanup of them?